# Bootstrap2 datatables next previous images not loading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, pagination

I am using bootstrap2 in my app and now I am impementing datatables in my app.I did all the way mentioned in this [site](http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2) like I added the js like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline"
} );
                var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
"sDom": "<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "sources/test1.json",
                    "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": "message" },
                        { "mData": "number" },
                        { "mData": "time" },
                        { "mData": "reason" }
                    ]
                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

and also these lines in the css file

```
table.table thead .sorting,
table.table thead .sorting_asc,
table.table thead .sorting_desc,
table.table thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.table thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand;
}

table.table thead .sorting { background: url('images/sort_both.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.table thead .sorting_asc { background: url('images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.table thead .sorting_desc { background: url('images/sort_desc.png') no-repeat center right; }

table.table thead .sorting_asc_disabled { background: url('images/sort_asc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.table thead .sorting_desc_disabled { background: url('images/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
```

But still the previous[image] next and 1,2,3.. are not coming.Please see the screenshot
Only the previous and next is showing.please tell me what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the pagination from `<Prev|Next >` to `<Prev|1|2|3|4|5|Next>` requires setting an additional [sPaginationType: "full_numbers"](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html) parameter.

If you look at the javascript code behind the [Bootstrap example](http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2) ([link](http://datatables.net/media/blog/bootstrap_2/DT_bootstrap.js)), you will see that the author actually adds some custom code for a special `bootstrap` pagination type.
I will leave it to you to read / test the code and decide if you should include it in your page, or just use the regular `full_number` setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It prints the like this `firstprevious1234nextlast`

Comment: Check the javascript link, look at the code, if it fits your needs add it to your code.

Comment: @SpringLearner check your css. this is may be a css issue.